# Conversion of far jmp from NASM/Intel to GAS/AT&T

Tags: assembly, x86, att, intel-syntax

I just have a simple line of NASM/Intel syntax assembly that I need in GAS/AT&T syntax. The line is

```
JMP   0x08:reload_CS
```

I couldn't find anything online, but I have tried:

```
jmp $0x08, reload_CS
jmp reload_CS + $0x08
```

Is one of these correct? If not could anyone provide the correct conversion? I'm not really sure how `0x08` effects `JMP   0x08:reload_CS` so an explanation of what is happening here would also be helpful.

Comment: You can always assemble with NASM, disassemble with `objdump`.  I forget the operand syntax but the AT&T mnemonic is `ljmp`.  This is a far jump to a new code segment; read Intel's manual for the `ptr16:16` version: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp

Comment: Should be `ljmp $0x08, $reload_CS`.